# How do you get an elytra in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you get an elytra in survival mode without creative mode, commands, mods, etc.? I tried googling it and I got no good answers.

Comment: I didn't anything find anything about getting an elytra at all.

Comment: Just by googling the title you can find tutorials and whatnot about how to get Elytra wings in Minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is the kind of question that should be googled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Minecraft Wiki: Elytra](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Elytra#Obtaining):

> #### Natural generation
>
> Elytra are found in [end cities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_cities). One pair of elytra is found within an [item frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_frame) in each [end ship](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_ship).